# After Jenkins update 2.6 -> 2.66 groovy script stopped work

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

For now with this script hundred of builds was done. After Jenkins update the groovy script is not running anymore. It is not getting even to the first stage. The error which I can see is misleading for me, as the 'Script' is the name of folder in my case. To be sure if everything is fine I regenerated the dir command with the jenkins built-in syntax pipeline generator and I got:

```
dir('Scripts\\CD\\stage_1') {
// some block
}
```

For the path `Scripts\CD\stage_1`

The error is saying following

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Scripts for class: groovy.lang.Binding
at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:224)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$4.call(Checker.java:241)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:238)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:28)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:1)
at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:173)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:162)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:162)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:19)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:35)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:32)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:32)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:330)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:82)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:242)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:230)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

For my code

```
#!groovy

node {

String step

currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"

checkout scm

sh "git rev-parse --short HEAD > .git/commit-id"
commit_id = readFile('.git/commit-id')

try {

stage 'Wait for running build'
dir('Scripts\\CD\\stage_1') {

        sh "./waitForRunningBuild"

}
```

Except updating from 2.6 to 2.66 I also updated all plugins to the latest ones and disabled CLI remote-smth (but it is rather for remote access over the ssh, not to run local commands I guess).

I have no clue, what does this error may mean as the Script name is the folder name, and there is no other `Script` name used inside.

Answer (score 0):

It occurred that multibranch plugin has troubles with the link inside Jenkinsfile. When I over write the Jenkins file content with the groovy script it started to go further.

The same issue for `ci` instead od `Scripts` was reported here - https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42830